# Snowflake query performance on unique element in variant column

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am querying a Snowflake view that contains many TB of semi-structured json data. When I query the variant column of interest for an element that is not unique among the records, results are returned within seconds:

```
SELECT json_data:element1 FROM table WHERE json_data:common_category = 'CATEGORY1';
```

When I query the variant column of interest for an element that is unique among the records, runtime slows to some unacceptable amount of time that I have not yet reached:

```
SELECT json_data:element1 FROM table WHERE json_data:unique_id = 'ID123456';
```

I believe that flattening the unique element into a relational form outside of the variant column would increase performance, but I am not a DBA with these permissions. Is there some way to tune my query such that looking up a single record based on the variant column json data will yield acceptable performance?

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake stores internally variant (json) data, in a independent column like structure for the 100+ most common elements, and the remainder in a leftovers like column. Those virtual columns have min/max, distribution like stats like normal columns have.

[notes 1](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/semistructured-considerations.html#semi-structured-data-files-and-columnarization)
[notes 2](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/faq-how-is-variant-data-stored)

This means on the major columns of your data, they can prune lots of unneeded partitions for reading (if your data is naturally ordered in a way the helps this).

It also means if your are using a couple of columns from the JSON it reads just those stripes, thus less IO.

Also when you select the whole blob like you do here, the second point does not come into play, as the READ for the SELECT and the READ for the WHERE are the same.

So for you queries you will see the first query all a small number of partition in.
For your second query you will see it plans to read all partitons.

If you alter your first query to:

```
SELECT json_data:common_category FROM table WHERE json_data:common_category = 'CATEGORY1';
```

You will see that the number of partition read is the same as the first example, but the number of bytes read should be a fraction.

Again like for normal tables you should always name all your columns and avoid `SELECT * FROM TABLE` as then the plan knows what to pull. You will see a statistically faster compile times when you name all your first order columns and all your variant columns.

In the context of making it faster:

if you have to have All the JSON columns then and

```
SELECT json_data FROM table WHERE json_data:common_category = 'CATEGORY1';
```

has acceptable speed then do:

```
SELECT json_data:common_category FROM table WHERE json_data:unique_id = 'ID123456';
SELECT json_data FROM table WHERE json_data:common_category = <answer from prior> and json_data:unique_id = 'ID123456';
```

this way the first query is reading the least amount form all partitions, and the second is reading the all from the partition that have to be read from..

Now this will not always work if for example the  `common_category` for `unique_id = 'ID123456'` is common to all partitions, but if you have some other column on all rows, that is sequential or aligned with the sort of the data (be that how you ingest the data thus the write order, or how you order the data if you have it clustered). Then select the filter column and the order columns then select the full match with the focusing effect of the ordering column.

We have very similar audit data the above pattern is used on, and other data that we store in multiple tables, some of the tables are super skinning and ordered (via cluster keys) and then we have a key that is insert_time of both that fast table and a wide/fat json table with all the "extra's" that are often not used, but are written in _insert_time order, thus finding the desired data in the fast table allow read the wide table with reduced partitions.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification around selecting explicit variant element names. Does this mean there is no other way to improve the performance of my second query due to the uniqueness of the condition element? Query times are still unacceptably slow.

Comment: `SELECT json_data.column1 FROM table WHERE json_data:unique_id = 'ID123456';` will be faster than `SELECT json_data FROM table WHERE json_data:unique_id = 'ID123456';` because less columns will be pulled. But there are two things at play the number of partitions that are read (or more to the point the number of partition that can be excluded from being read) and the number of columns that are read from those partitions.

Comment: `SELECT json_data:common_category FROM table WHERE json_data:unique_id = 'ID123456';` does not have acceptable speed. Any time the `unique_id` is added as a condition the query does not run in a reasonable about of time. I have edited my question with the select of a single explicit element of json_data but my question remains the same.

Comment: I feel I have covered that case, if you are using a Minor element of the JSON you will most likely doing a full table scan, which will have poor performance. Yes, having things as "full" columns will give better performance, on columns that are sparsely populated, but then your meta data will increase and you still might end up with full table scans.

Comment: The column unique_id is not sparsely populated. Running a query with unique_id in the where clause takes > 8 minutes. Your answer seems to be that it is not possible to yield acceptable performance. I have never experienced a situation where it took 8 minutes to query an id in a relational column.

Comment: What I am trying to say is if you have "Many TB of data" it will take a while to read it all. I am also trying to say at it's most simplest snowflake is "full table scans" and under many situations the fully tables (via rows or columns) does not need to be all data read. Given there are no indexes, the only way to prune is based of value distribution in for the columns you are reading. If the column you very heavily care about "unique_id" is critical to many queries, you will see better performance making it a real column (even if it present auto promoted to a column under the hood).

Comment: indexes are just a second table, and the query pattern I suggested is in effect building your own index. We do this for a couple of tables, because we align the data with respect to how the system works. I hear you asking how can I make something go faster, and my suggestion is to understand how it works, and go with the flow.